# Editing a File on Google App Engine in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was seeing this in my Google App Engine Log:

```
...
      File "/base/data/home/apps/s~just-terminus-94303/1.384249106864280829/appengine_config.py", line 5, in <module>
        vendor.add('google-api-python-client')
...
ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access google-api-python-client: No such virtualenv or site directory
```

I edited the appengine_config.py file from

```
vendor.add('google-api-python-client')
```

to

```
vendor.add('googleapiclient')
```

and I commit the change but I am still getting the same exact error as above.  How do I get my change to update?

Comment: So I was able to edit it through the console, but I now get a similar error with the new code.  Does anyone know why this error is coming up?

Answer (score 0):

The `vendor.add()` method is used to add a folder to your application's python path. It should be a root directory that contains python packages that you may have installed using `pip`'s target option. It should not point directly to a python module.

```python
vendor.add('lib')  # lib contains googleapiclient/
```